# Logkeys keylogger not working on Ubuntu box in Vagrant; appears to not see keyboard events

Tags: virtualbox, programming, tty, vagrant

I'm trying to get [logkeys](https://github.com/kernc/logkeys) to work on an "ubuntu/precise64" Vagrant box for a work project, but nothing is getting logged.  I've spent several hours reading and trying to track down the issue.

The logkeys code finds the correct device "/dev/input/event2" and fopens it:

```
input_fd = open(args.device.c_str(), O_RDONLY);
```

The code is then supposed to enter a while loop when it reads input:

```
while (read(input_fd, &event, sizeof(struct input_event)) > 0) {
```

The while loop isn't actually entered (confirmed with debug statements). It appears that no keyboard events are actually happening.  This could all be because I'm running this is a VM, but I'm not sure as some other things check out. E.g., per several posts such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775461/linux-keyboard-event-capturing-dev-inputx), it appears that event2 is in fact the correct device in my Ubuntu VM:

```
cat /proc/bus/input/devices
...
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab41
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input2
...
B: EV=120013
...
```

I've confirmed that logkeys has actually chosen to listen to event2 through debug statements to console added to the code.

When I `cat /dev/input/event2`, and type, the keystrokes are shown on console.  I had thought that that was an accurate test of determining the correct event to listen to; however, when I `cat /dev/input/event4`, which is supposed to be a mouse, the same thing happens - keystrokes echoed on console.

I don't have an Ubuntu machine to test on.  I could try it on an VirtualBox machine with an Ubuntu ISO, but don't follow how that would be different than what I'm doing now.  I have tried other Vagrant Ubuntu boxes as well (ubuntu/trusty and another one) with no change.  I do like the speed and convenience of doing my dev on the Vagrant box.  Well, it's usually pretty fast and convenient, but not at the moment.

Does anyone have any insight on what might be going on, and what I'm missing?

Thanks very much, jz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my question for posterity, in case anyone ever does something similar, which is highly unlikely!

In my tests, I had only been connecting to the box with `vagrant ssh`, and was typing in my original terminal window.  I changed my Vagrant file to include a gui, with `config.vm.provider "virtualbox" { |v| v.gui = true }`, and vagrant launched a CLI window with the guest.  The typing in *that* terminal worked, and the debug was output to the original terminal.

Unfortunately I don't have time to investigate exactly why the keystrokes on the host box weren't showing up in the guest ... probably something obvious I'm missing.  If anyone has a good idea, please post as I'm interested.